# Postgres query array elements inside JSON?

Tags: postgresql

I have Postgres 11 table called fb_designs that has a `json` column with data structured like so:

```
{
    "listings": [
       {
            "id": "KTyneMdrAhAEKyC9Aylf",
            "active": true
        },
        {
            "id": "ZcjK9M4tuwhWWdK8WcfX",
            "active": false
        }
    ]
}
```

and a `tags` column in a `character varying[]` format as so `{dWLaRWChaThFPH6b3BpA,BrYiPaUiou020hsmRugR}`.  Both lengths are undefined.

What I am trying to do is produce a some queries that will let me say in laymans terms,

> show me all results where at all items.listings has an
>   active status and tags contains `BrYiPaUiou020hsmRugR`

I got this far, however I'm not sure how to add in `WHERE uid = "foo"`, `WHERE tags contains "foo", "bar` and `WHERE title is like %hoot%`

```
SELECT id, title, tags, selected_preview_image, items
FROM  fb_designs r, json_array_elements(r.items#>'{listings}') obj 
WHERE  obj->>'active' = 'true' 
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score -1):

If they are all true, then none of them are false.  Sounds like you want to negate the containment operation over false.

```
select * from fb_designs where 
    not items::jsonb @> '{"listings":[{"active": false}]}'
    and tags && ARRAY['BrYiPaUiou020hsmRugR']::varchar[]
```

Comment: Basically I want to find all records where either the listings.active are all true, or all false.  I'll give your code a go

Comment: It doesn't seem to like the array bit
`ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying[] && text[]
LINE 3: AND tags && ARRAY['jl3kibkh0XS9a8JP7r5P']`

Comment: Right you need to cast the array to the correct type (although really I would change the column to be a text[] unless you have a good reason for it to be otherwise.)